# Access partial view's model in parent view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm trying to access view model of a partial view in it's parent view (Home page) but, unable to do so!

My scenerio: I have a partial view with it's own controller and view model. there are 3 lists being populated from DB in partial view's model: Countries, cities, and categories.

I want to show categories on both partial view and it's parent with different pattern.

Note: As the partial view is being used on other pages (views) also so, I can't put Categories in Home view model instead of partial view model! And putting Categories list in both view models will cause double DB call for same data!

Can anyone please help in this regards. Thanks

Comment: Put Categories in ViewBag and access it in partialview or in parentview.

Comment: Short answer - You cant.A view only has access to its own view data. You can always cache the data if your concerned with hitting the database twice or include in in the HomePage view model and then pass it to the partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access partial view's model in parent view. But you can share data between them with `HttpContext.Items`.

```
@{
    this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["Stuff"] = "some-data";
}
```

this data is valid for a single HTTP Request.

More info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx

[When can we use HttpContext.Current.Items to stores data in ASP.NET?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146455/When-can-we-use-HttpContext-Current-Items-to-store)

**Edit:** link corrected.