# How to access the Model of a partial view in the parent view?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had a view that contained the following script:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {
    var messages = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Messages)); // Accessing the Model here.
    $.each(messages, function (index, item) {
        addMessageRow(item, false);
    });
    $("#btnAddMessage").on("click", function () {
        addMessageRow();
    });
    // More code
});
```

.. which worked just fine. Then, I converted it to a partial view which I display in a bootstrap modal. As far as I know, the script section doesn't work in the modal/partial view (and it didn't). So, I moved the javascript code to the parent view to be executed right after calling the `.modal` method:

```javascript
$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function () {
    $("#childModalContent").load(this.href, function () {
        $("#childModal").modal({ keyboard: true }, "show");

        var messages = /*GetMessagesAsJson();*/          // How to get the Messages here?
        $.each(messages, function (index, item) {
            addMessageRow(item, false);
        });
        $("#btnAddMessage").on("click", function () {    // This works just fine.
            addMessageRow();
        });

    });
    return false;
});
```

..which worked, except that I don't know how to get the `Messages` collection now because it belongs to the Model of the partial view. This is how the partial view gets its model:

```c#
public ActionResult Edit(int? parentId, int? childId)
{
    if (parentId == null || childId == null) { /*BadRequest*/ }

    child child = GetChild(parentId, childId);
    if (child == null) { /*NotFound*/ }

    return PartialView("_Edit", child);
}
```

And here's how the action is called:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "ControllerName", 
                 new {parentId = Model.ParentId, childId = item.Id },
                 new { @class = "btn btn-default", data_modal = "" })
```

As the `.on("click")` function above shows, clicking this link loads the partial view as a model. For this to work, I have the following placeholder in the parent view:

```html
<div id="childModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="childModalContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I checked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30476280/8967612). The answer there suggests passing the relevant data between the views but I'm not sure how to do that considering that the partial view is returned by the controller as shown above.

**How can I execute javascript code on the partial (modal) view accessing its Model?**

Comment: Is it a .net framework project? I have done a similar thing in .net core, and it should just work for .net framework too. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Yes, it's a .NET Framework project. Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1 - Data inside the partial view is static i.e. Data model of partial view doesn't change after parent view has been loaded**

- From the action method, return view not partial view
- Create another partial view which accepts the same model as the partial view. Put all JS code here
- Now we have two partial views. One with HTML and another with JS code. Call both of them from the parent view. HTML partial view will go inside the HTML and JS code partial view will go in the Scripts section.
- The partial view with JS code is same as any other partial view but only has JS code. See example below

Here is an example in .net core:

Action method

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Search(SearchModel model)
    {
        var vm = _someService.GetData(model);

        return View(vm);

    }
```

Parent View

```
@model SomeViewModelOfYourChoice


<section class="filter-section">
   //Render HTML partial view
   @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SearchResultsFiltersPartial", Model); }
</section>

@section scripts{
    //Render JS code partial view
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SearchResultsScriptsPartial", Model); }

}
```

Partial view with JS only code

```
@model PartialViewModelOfYourChoice

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     // Model is now available here e.g. @Model   
     //All your JS code here
 });
</script>
```

**Scenario 2 - Data inside the partial view is dynamic i.e data changes every time the partial view is loaded**

- Return JSON from your action method, not partial view(see example below)
- Don't pass any model inside the partial view
- On bootstrap modal show event fetch the data from the action and set the result(JSON) in a variable
- Run the JS code with the result(JSON)

Here is an example

Return the JSON from the action method

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? parentId, int? childId)
{
   if (parentId == null || childId == null) { /*BadRequest*/ }

   child child = GetChild(parentId, childId);
   if (child == null) { /*NotFound*/ }

   return Json(child,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Parent View

```
@model SomeViewModelOfYourChoice


<section class="filter-section">
   //Render HTML partial view. Note that model is not passed here
   @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SearchResultsFiltersPartial"); }
</section>        
}
```

On anchor click call the action method.

```
//Generate the URL
// I believe that Model.ParentId will remain the same but you need to dynamically pass the item.id
var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Edit", "ControllerName", new {parentId = Model.ParentId, childId = item.Id }))';
// Call action method
$.ajax({url: url,type: 'GET',contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            messages = result;
            //Run your rest of the JS code here   
         }
       });
```

Comment: If I return a view instead of a partial view, how can I display it as a modal when a link is clicked? I edited the question to show how I currently call the action.

Comment: That is easy. Add the click event on the anchor tag and show the modal by manually calling the modal show method. If you are using bootstrap then here is an example - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#modalshow

Comment: That's not my point. In your example, you're directly rendering the view in the parent (right?) I'm kind of new to ASP.NET and web development in general so maybe it's something simple that I'm missing. I don't see how `Html.RenderPartial` can be used to display the partial view in a model though.

Comment: Does the data in @Model.Messages change on every click or is it static after the parent view has been loaded?

Comment: On each click, a call is made to the `Edit` action with the `Id` of the `Child`. The action then returns a partial view with a specific `Child` object as the model. The `Child` class has a `Messages` property of type `List<string>`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I have edited the answer. Please see scenario 2.

Comment: Please [continue the discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/212539/discussion-between-shobhit-vaish-and-ahmed-abdelhameed).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with a hacky workaround. It does the job but it's inefficient because now I have to make an AJAX request to get the child object each time the link is clicked although I already have the same object as the Model of the partial view (just don't know how to access it!)

So, here's what I did. I first added an action to return the child object:

```c#
public ActionResult GetChild(int id)
{
    var child = _context.ChildEntityDbSet.Find(id);
    if (child == null) { return HttpNotFound(); }

    return this.JsonEx(child, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

..then a call is made to that action to retrieve that object each time the "Edit" link is clicked to show the modal view:

```javascript
var currentChild;

$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function () {
    currentChild = null;
    var childId = $(this).attr("data-child-id");
    var modalUrl = this.href;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/GetChild/" + childId
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        currentChild = data;
        if (currentChild != null) { showModal(modalUrl); }
    })
    .fail(function () {
        // Handle
    });

    return false;
});
```

And then I access the `messages` via the `currentChild` object instead of the Model:

```javascript
$("#childModal").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
    // Add existing messages as rows.
    if (currentChild != null) {
        var messages = currentChild.messages;
        $.each(messages, function (index, item) {
            addMessageRow(item, false);
        });
    }

    $("#btnAddMessage").on("click", function () {
        addMessageRow();
    });
    // More code
});
```

I still hope that someone could come up with a better solution.